# Load data to UITableView

Tags: xcode, swift

I have data saved like this:

```
var mineSpillere = ["erik", "tom", "phil"]
```

How can i add that data to a UITableView by pressing a UIButton like this?:

```
@IBAction func backButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Press this button here to add the "mineSpillere" data to myTableView
}
```

Comment: When you click a button, add a table view and set the delegate.

Comment: @Amit89 - Add a table view? The table view is already there, but it is empty. I want to add the data on a button action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the data source of the table view inside the IBAction. so like this:

```
@IBAction func backButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    myTableView.dataSource = self
    // Loading from NSUserDefaults:
    // Please name it something better than array I couldn't come up with any names.
    if let array = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("key") as? [String]   
    { 
          // The key exists in user defaults 
    }
    else 
    { 
          // The key doesn't exist in the user defaults, do some error handling here. 
    }
}
```

And then implement the data source:

```
extension MyVC : UITableViewDataSource
{
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return mineSpillere.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel!.text = mineSpillere[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "extension MyVC : UITableViewDataSource"?

Comment: MyVC is basically the view controller you are using where this tableView is. The class in which the IBAction function is present.

Comment: How should i do this if i have this: var mineSpillere = [String]() and the data is saved to a key using NSUserDefault?

Comment: Then load up the `mineSpillere` array inside the `IBAction func`. So something like this: `mineSpillere =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("key") as? [String] `. If you do it this way you can set the dataSource in viewDidLoad, and call `tableView.reloadData` inside the function (this is actually a better way to do it.

Comment: WOW thanks! It worked!! How can i do something like, to check if the key exist?

Comment: @Eri-Sklii See edit with the if statements in the IBAction function

Comment: Thanks again, and the last question; How can i check if the "var mineSpillere" contains anything?

Comment: If its an optional use an if let binding like `if let mineSpillere = mineSpillere where mineSpillere.count > 0 { // Exists } else { // Nope nothing }`. If its just simply a `[String]` without the ? at the end just check if the count > 0

Comment: It´s simple as this: var mineSpillere = [String]()

Comment: So to check if anything exists just do `if mineSpillere.count > 0 { // There is some value in here } else { // Nothing... }